# Passing JavaScript variable to PHP on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

I am trying to change text in a div depending on value change on a dropdown box. The dropdown box values are populated from MySQL using PHP. I am loading the dropdown box on page load.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#products').change(function(){

var idval=$('#products').val();
$.ajax
        (   {
                type: "post",
                url: "my.php",
                data: {winner_id:idval}, 
                success: function(response)
                { alert("The winner was passed!")},
            }
        );

 <?php 
require_once 'config.php';


$iid=$_GET['winner_id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Products where prod_id = ".$iid;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$prodCredit="Credit :".$row["prod_price"];
$time="estmated time is  :".$row["prod_time"];

 ?> 
$('#esdTime').text(' <?php echo $prodCredit ?> ' );
$('#credit').text(' <?php echo $time ?> ' );

   });

  });

</script>
```

I am not getting results.

Let me know how can I assign JavaScript value `idval` to PHP variable `$iid` value.

Comment: php is server side code - executed **before** page load. javascript is client side code - executed **after** page load. so your javascript code cannot modify/impact the php code as it has already run. you need to put your php code into a separate file, and then use the `success: function(response)` to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you would want a the php script to be in a separate file that you could call Have the php file return an array or json object. Have the callback success function append the new options to the html select. The following is a ruffexample

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#products').change(function(){

 var idval=$('#products').val();
$.ajax
    (   {
            type: "post",
            url: "my.php",
            data: {winner_id:idval}, 
            success: function(response){
              for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                  $("#idofyourselect").append("<option val='" +response[i]+"'>" + response[i] + "</option>");
              }
            },
        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: is    $("#idofyourselect")  same as $('#products'). which is ID of dropDownbox.   Because Drop down box has value like 101:Green .  I use strinf functions to get 101 from that and use 101 in select statement to get other columns from table using 101.     Also Would   winner_id  in  data: {winner_id:idval}   not holds value of variable  idval ???

Comment: I would assume that it is the #products selector without looking more into your code. This is just a ruff example of how you could do it. You may also have to remove all the previous options before you append the new ones so its doesn't have any repeats. The main thing is that your php file has to be separate from your html and javascript. You will just load the php scripts data in through a ajax request and then use javascript to manipulate the DOM.